# Why do I need `std::type_identity_t` to enable implicit type conversion here?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++20, implicit-conversion, c++-templates

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <format>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ... Args>
struct FmtString {
    std::format_string<Args ...> text;

    template <typename StringCompatible>
    requires (std::convertible_to<StringCompatible, std::string_view>)
    consteval FmtString(StringCompatible const& description)
        : text(description)
        {}
};

template <typename ... Args>
void fails(FmtString<Args ...> const&, Args&& ...) noexcept {}

template <typename... Args>
using FmtStringArgIdentity = FmtString<std::type_identity_t<Args> ...>;

template <typename ... Args>
void works(FmtStringArgIdentity<Args ...> const&, Args&& ...) noexcept {}

int main() {
    works("test {}", 42);
    fails("test {}", 42);
}
```

GCC error message:

```cpp
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:28:10: error: no matching function for call to 'fails(const char [8], int)'
   28 |     fails("test {}", 42);
      |     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:18:6: note: candidate: 'template<class ... Args> void fails(const FmtString<Args ...>&, Args&& ...)'
   18 | void fails(FmtString<Args ...> const&, Args&& ...) noexcept {}
      |      ^~~~~
<source>:18:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:28:10: note:   mismatched types 'const FmtString<Args ...>' and 'const char [8]'
   28 |     fails("test {}", 42);
      |     ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Compiler returned: 1
```

Looking on the source code of [libfmt](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) I was able to make my code work. Unfortunately, I don't understand why this works or why the template argument deduction fails.

What is the problem with the `fails` call and why does the `works` call solve this?

[Live-Code](https://godbolt.org/z/WrjzvKMWb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simpler example with the same effect:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct foo {
    template <typename U>
    foo(U u) {}
};

template <typename T>
void fails(foo<T>,T) {}

template <typename T>
void works(std::type_identity_t<foo<T>>,T) {}

int main()
{
    fails(12.0,42); // error
    works(12.0,42);
}
```

You cannot deduce `int` from `12.0` that would be used to convert to a `foo<int>`. There is simply no relation between `double` used as template argument to the constructor and `int` used to instantiate `foo<int>`. Any `foo<T>` has a converting constructor from `double` to `foo<T>`.

`std::type_identity` is a non-deduced context. For `works<T>`, the `T` is only deduced from `42`, and `works<int>` is instantiated to get `works<int>(foo<int>,int)`. Only now the implicit conversion kicks in and `12.0` can be converted to `foo<int>` via the converting constructor.

Comment: In order to complement @463035818_is_not_an_ai answer, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts, rule #1